# Disable Hardware & Software Interrupts

Tags: assembly, x86, atomic, interrupt, critical-section

Is it possible to disable all interrupts with a ASM/C/C++ program to get full control about the processor?

If yes -> how?

If not -> how do "atomic" operation system calls work (for example entering a critical section)?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to state which processor you're using. And which OS if any. On modern desktop/server operating system, userland code usually runs in an unprivileged mode preventing you from doing this.

Comment: MS Windows (XP SP2/SP3, Vista, 7) x86 and x64 versions,
modern intel processors (e.g. Intel Core 2 Duo)

Comment: re: atomic operations: [Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39393850) describes how/why `lock cmpxchg [rdi], ecx` is atomic.  Disabling interrupts on the current core would be useless anyway on a multi-core machine; even disabling interrupts on all cores wouldn't work if another core is already running another thread of the same program.

Answer (score 12):

In x86 assembly the the commands are

- `sti` set interrupt enable bit
- `cli` clear interrupt enable bit

These commands set and clear the [IF Flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IF_(x86_flag)). When the IF flag is set, the CPU will handle hardware interrupts, and when it is clear the CPU will ignore hardware interrupts. It does not affect the handling of non-maskable interrupts though, nor does it affect software interrupts or exceptions. These instructions also don't work in unprivileged mode (usually everything higher than ring 0, depending on [IOPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOPL))  though.

Comment: you got it backwards. STI enables interrupts. CLI disables.

Comment: It also does not disable software interrupts or exceptions

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments and edits: STI enables interrupts, CLI disables interrupts is indeed correct. I was sure it was the other way round, but I learned my assembly on a C64, so I looked it up: The 6510 had CLI do disable and STI to enable. I'm confused;-)

Answer (score 3):

on x86 and most other modern processors you can get atomic instructions.  Ones that are GURANTEED not to be finished executing before another thread/processor can access that memory.

Under Win32 you have the Interlocked* functions that abstract that from you on supported platforms.

On a MIPS  a lot of instruction can have a .I added to the end of the instruction to guarantee interlocking.

Comment: On a x86 you can prefix certain instructions with "lock" to make them atomic.

Comment: For what platform?  If its for windows then http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684122(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

The x86 has an interrupt flag (IF) in the FLAGS register. When this flag is set to 0, hardware interrupts are disabled, otherwise they are enabled. The command cli sets this flag to 0, and sti sets it to 1. Instructions that load values into the FLAGS register (such as popf and iret) may also modify this flag.

good luck!